# Iframe on xsl templatee

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

Please help me with the below XSL template. I am using iframe to display video but I'm keep getting error.

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <div id="listitem-{@ID}">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="catalog-item">                  
               <img height="70" width="70" class="catalog-icon pull-left"><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="@Picture" /></xsl:attribute></img>                  
               <span class="catalog-item-title"><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></span>
               <div class="aliases">Aliases: <xsl:value-of select="@Aliases" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> </div>
            </div> 
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">    
               <div class="catalog-descr"><xsl:value-of select="@Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></div> 
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="video-responsive">
                <iframe width="420" height="315" src="{@Youtube}"></iframe>
                </div>                   
            </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You will  need to describe which error you get and how the input data looks.

Comment: Error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer."

Comment: So you get that error when using SharePoint? Did you follow the suggestion "To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in .." to find out more? As the problem seems related to SharePoint and/or Web Parts, I suggest you add the relevant tags to the question, it does not seem to be an XSLT problem.